# Runge-Kutta implemented on Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve differential equations numerically, so I am trying to write a 4th -order Runge-Kutta program for Mathematica (I know `NDSolve` does this, but I want to do my own). I ran into some trouble though, as my program just loops infinitely.

```
RK[a_,b_,y0_,n_,f_]:= Module[{},
h=(b-a)/n;
X = Table[a+k*h, {k,0,n} ];
Y = Table[y0, {k,0,n} ];
For[j=1, j<n, j++,
k1 = f[X[[j]],Y[[j]]];
k2 = f[X[[j]]+(h/2),Y[[j]]+h*(k1/2)];
k3 = f[X[[j]]+(h/2),Y[[j]]+h*(k2/2)];
k4 = f[X[[j+1]],Y[[j]]+h*k3];
Y[[j+1]]= Y[[j]]+(h/6)(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4);
];
Return[Transpose[{X,Y}]];
];
```

I don't think my issue is with the algortithm though... I think its with my definition of the differential equation. I was honestly pretty lost on how I do this, but this is what I came up with:

```
f[x_,y_] = y - (x^2)(y)^2;
RK[0,10,2,50,f[x,Function[x,y[x]]]]
```

I tried defining it as a function of two variables... but I think I might have done some thing wrong.

If this is wrong...how do I define a differential equation as a function of two variables?

Comment: there are many problems in your code. First you do not find `k4`. Second, you need `;` between end of the `For` loops and the `Return[]` statement. Also you do not need an explicit `Return`. Also the call is wrong.  Why not just `RK[0, 2, 2, 5, f[x, x]]` ? Try to correct these first and see. btw, there is lots of RK4 code in this forum, many questions were asked about it before. If you google, you'll find examples.

Comment: The k4 I just messed up in post...its correct in my code. Ill fix the others, thank you.

Comment: I am not sure how f[x,x] is equivalent...or correct. Wont that just solve x - x^4?

Comment: You also failed to localize any variables within `Module`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me

```
RK[a_, b_, y0_, n_, f_] := Module[{X, Y, j, k1, k2, k3, k4, h},
  h = (b - a)/n;
  X = Table[a + k*h, {k, 0, n}];
  Y = Table[y0, {k, 0, n}];
  For[j = 1, j < n, j++, k1 = f[X[[j]], Y[[j]]];
   k2 = f[X[[j]] + (h/2), Y[[j]] + h*(k1/2)];
   k3 = f[X[[j]] + (h/2), Y[[j]] + h*(k2/2)];
   k4 = f[X[[j + 1]], Y[[j]] + h*k3];
   Y[[j + 1]] = Y[[j]] + (h/6) (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4);
   ];

   Transpose[{X, Y}]
  ];

f[x_, y_] := y - (x^2) (y)^2;
RK[0, 2, 2, 5, f] // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice fix on the output... the first one destroyed my browser! Thanks for being so helpful!

Answer (score 10):

Nasser already pointed out many mistakes, so I won't go into those.

[`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) would allow for a much cleaner implementation.

Below, `RK4step[f,h]` denotes a function which takes a pair of $\{t,y(t)\}$ values, and produces the next one at $t+h$, assuming that $y'(t) = f(t, y(t))$.

```
ClearAll[RK4step]
RK4step[f_, h_][{t_, y_}] :=
 Module[{k1, k2, k3, k4},
  k1 = f[t,       y];
  k2 = f[t + h/2, y + h k1/2];
  k3 = f[t + h/2, y + h k2/2];
  k4 = f[t + h,   y + h k3];
  {t + h, y + h/6*(k1 + 2 k2 + 2 k3 + k4)}
 ]
```

We can use `NestList` to take a starting pair $\{t_0, y(t_0)\}$, and repeatedly propagate the time using `RK4step`.

```
res = 
 NestList[
  RK4step[-#2 &, 0.1], (* #2 & is short for f where f[t_, y_] := -y, look up Function *)
  {0.0, 1.0}, (* this is {t0, y(t0)} *)
  100 (* compute this many steps *)
 ]

ListPlot[res, PlotRange -> All]
```

More complex example, a harmonic oscillator:

```
f[t_, {x_, v_}] := {v, -x}

res = NestList[
   RK4step[f, 0.1],
   {0.0, {1.0, 0.0}},
   100 
   ];

ListPlot[
 Transpose[{res[[All, 1]], res[[All, 2, 1]]}]
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the spunked up version. I am a Mathematica Ignoramus, so I am gonna stick with Nasser's fix on my code. Yours looks cool, but its beyond me! Thanks for being so helpful!

Comment: @ragnvaldr.js Recommended reading: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/12

Comment: Thanks... I had no clue that the For loop should be avoided in Mathematica. For what I am doing, this will work, but Ill try and work through your solution for future use... Thanks!

Comment: @ragnvaldr.js What, specifically, is unclear in the `NestList` solution? It is much closer to the textbook description of the method than a procedural loop.

Comment: I'm sure it is... but I'm an amatuer Java Developer so the For loop is just second nature to me. I guess I am confused as the `res = ...` stuff. The added info helps... The syntax is still just unfamiliar.

Comment: @ragnvaldr.js You mean it's unclear to you what `NestList` does? Did you check the documentation, which I linked? I think the first example there is quite informative.

Comment: No... I missed it. That makes sense now.. thanks!

Comment: @Szabolcs Your code is perfect (+1), see my answer  on https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221848/problems-with-runge-kutta-methods-for-different-functions/221865?noredirect=1#comment564843_221865