# Help me solve for the equations of motion for a double spherical pendulum

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I've been working on a project to simulate the movement of a double spherical pendulum through Lagrangian mechanics. I found [this link](https://www.assignmentexpert.com/homework-answers/physics-answer-69717.pdf), which has the equations of motion in. I need to solve for the second time derivative of `theta1`, `phi1`, `theta2`, and `phi2`.

What I did was change all the time derivative symbols (') and replace them with a d meaning that `theta1'` is now `theta1d` etc. I'm certain that this is probably wrong but I'm not sure how I would do it otherwise

```
vars = {theta1dd, phi1dd, theta2dd, phi2dd}
Equations = {equations of movement}

Solve[equations, vars]
```

Is this incorrect syntax? If so, what should I do?

P.S. I'm only 16 so i'm sorry for my ignorance

Comment: You are trying to solve a **differential equation**, i.e. an equation in which the unknown is a *function*, given some conditions on its values and the values of its derivatives. Start by looking up [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html) and perusing [How To Solve a Differential Equation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/SolveADifferentialEquation.html).

Comment: Here is a simple example: `DSolve[{y[x] == y'[x], y[0] == 1}, y[x], x]`. Here we ask, what is the function $y(x)$ that is everywhere equal to its own first derivative $y'(x)$, and that has a value of 1 when its argument is 0? In this case, the answer is $y(x)=e^x$, as the above `DSolve` expression will tell you. It's a pretty deep rabbit hole...

Comment: Here is a treatment of a spherical pendulum as part of an introductory college course on Mathematica: [MATHEMATICA TUTORIAL for the Second Course. Part III: Spherical pendulum](http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am34/Mathematica/ch3/spherical.html) from Prof. Vladimir Dobrushkin at Brown.

Comment: @MarcoB thanks soooo much. The paper from the professor is PERFECT, and I believe the final bit of code is just what I need to solve. :D thanks so much dude

Comment: I’m very glad it helped!

Comment: aww man, im really dying, do you have any idea what the functions would be, i'm confused af

Comment: cause like, i'm really inexperienced with this type of stuff

Comment: @MarcoB I'm sorry for asking so many question, but how would I find the functions? do i just input the equations of motion into the equations part? and is something like theta1'' = theta1dotdot

Comment: The way you ask questions here is unacceptable. You do not show any preliminary work, and, moreover, your goal was to learn Java, not MA!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm often a little bit unsure about how to go about entering everything I need into `DSolve` and `NDSolve`, so I usually like to start with the simplest example I can, and then slowly work my way up to what I actually want to do.

**I would strongly recommend trying to work through these on your own as much as possible if you want to improve your understanding.** But if you get stuck, I've added quite a bit of code here. I find this sort of simulation really interesting, so I couldn't help but look into it. There are some really nice answers for a 2D coupled pendulum on [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48059/animation-of-double-pendulum?rq=1) question, so I hope that my answer here can help with the 3D case.

The `VariationalMethods` package has a nice function `EulerEquations` which automatically calculates the Euler-Lagrange equation for each variable and saves some extra work, so I'll be using it here.

---

**Simple Pendulum:**

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
x[t_] := Sin[θ[t]]
y[t_] := -Cos[θ[t]]
L = 1/2 m l^2 (x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2) - m g l y[t] // FullSimplify
ee = EulerEquations[L, θ[t], t]
```

> $\frac{1}{2} l m \left(2 g \cos (\theta (t))+l \theta '(t)^2\right)$
>
> $-l m \left(g \sin (\theta (t))+l \theta ''(t)\right)=0$

Here I'm importing the `VariationalMethods` package, and then defining my Cartesian coordinates `x[t]` and `y[t]`. The Lagrangian is just the kinetic energy ($1/2mv^2$) minus the potential energy ($mgy$). Then, I ask `EulerEquations` to provide the Euler-Lagrange equations for the Lagrangian with respect to the coordinate $\theta(t)$ and independent variable $t$.

While I believe there is a closed form for the simple pendulum that relies on non-elementary functions, it's difficult to find analytical expressions for differential equations. Since the double spherical pendulum certainly won't have an analytical expression, I'll start using `NDSolve` here which provides a numerical result.

```
sol = First@NDSolve[{
    ee /. {m -> 1, l -> 1, g -> 9.81},
    θ'[0] == 0,
    θ[0] == π/8
    },
   θ[t],
   {t, 0, 20}
   ];
```

I'm replacing the mass $m$, the length $l$, and acceleration due to gravity $g$ in the Euler-Lagrange equation (using `/.`) before I ask it to solve the equation. There are a number of ways that you could specify these values, including just defining global variables `m = 1; l = 1; g = 9.81` or making the functions accept these as arguments, but either way these should have numerical values by the time you call `NDSolve`.

Then I add in my initial conditions where I've set the angular velocity $\theta'(0)$ to 0, and the initial angle $\theta(0)$ to $\pi/8$. I'm asking it to solve for $\theta(t)$ for $t$ ranging from 0 to 20. It's unitless here, but if we assume $m$, $l$, and $g$ were in base SI units, we can read this as 0 seconds to 20 seconds.

Next, I want to plot this result to see what happened. I'm going to plot it 2 ways: first I'll plot $\theta(t)$ against $t$ to make sure it looks sinusoidal (I started with a small angle so it should be pretty close). Second, I want to see the motion of the pendulum.

```
Plot[
  θ[t] /. sol, 
  {t, 0, 20}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "θ(t)"}, 
  PlotRange -> {-π, π}
]
ParametricPlot[
  {x[t], y[t]} /. sol, 
  {t, 0, 10}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}
]
```

[image: Simple pendulum plot of angle vs time.]

[image: Simple pendulum plot of x and y coordinates.]

The second graph doesn't look all that interesting, but shows us the expected motion of a pendulum.

---

**Spherical Pendulum:**

I think I've explained most of the steps for the simple pendulum, so I'll include less explanation for these next cases.

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
x[t_] := Sin[θ[t]] Cos[ϕ[t]]
y[t_] := Sin[θ[t]] Sin[ϕ[t]]
z[t_] := -Cos[θ[t]]
L = m l^2 (x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2 + z'[t]^2)/2 - m g l z[t] // FullSimplify;
ee = EulerEquations[L, {ϕ[t], θ[t]}, t];
sol = First@NDSolve[{
     Splice[ee/.{m -> 1, l -> 1, g -> 9.81}],
     ϕ'[0] == 0.5,
     θ'[0] == 0,
     ϕ[0] == 0,
     θ[0] == π/8
     },
    {ϕ[t], θ[t]},
    {t, 0, 100}
    ];
ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol, {t, 0, 100}]
```

[image: Parametric plot of spherical pendulum.]

For a different set of starting conditions ($\theta(0) = \pi/2$ and only going up to a maximum time of 50), I get:

[image: Parametric plot of spherical pendulum with larger starting angle.]

---

**Double Spherical Pendulum:**

Now that we understand a bit more about how `NDSolve` works and how to specify the arguments, we can try the toughest one. Notice that I defined the lengths `l1` and `l2` here. This helped me to keep the definitions of the Cartesian coordinates and the Lagrangian relatively short. This isn't my favourite way of doing it, but I haven't been able to figure out a good way to keep the definitions simple and not have the Cartesian coordinates include the lengths.

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
l1 = 1;
l2 = 1;
x1[t_] := l1 Sin[θ1[t]] Cos[ϕ1[t]]
y1[t_] := l1 Sin[θ1[t]] Sin[ϕ1[t]]
z1[t_] := -l1 Cos[θ1[t]]
x2[t_] := x1[t] + l2 Sin[θ2[t]] Cos[ϕ2[t]]
y2[t_] := y1[t] + l2 Sin[θ2[t]] Sin[ϕ2[t]]
z2[t_] := z1[t] - l2 Cos[θ2[t]]
L = m1 (x1'[t]^2 + y1'[t]^2 + z1'[t]^2)/2 + 
    m2 (x2'[t]^2 + y2'[t]^2 + z2'[t]^2)/2 - m1 g  z1[t] - 
    m2 g  z2[t] // FullSimplify;
ee = EulerEquations[
   L, {ϕ1[t], θ1[t], ϕ2[t], θ2[t]}, t];
sol = First@NDSolve[{
     Splice[ee /. {m1 -> 1, m2 -> 1, g -> 9.81}],
     ϕ1'[0] == 0.75,
     ϕ2'[0] == -0.215,
     θ1'[0] == 0.2,
     θ2'[0] == -0.09,
     ϕ1[0] == 0.5,
     ϕ2[0] == 0,
     θ1[0] == 4 π/8,
     θ2[0] == π/8
     },
    {ϕ1[t], θ1[t], ϕ2[t], θ2[t]},
    {t, 0, 100},
    Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}
    ];
ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate[{{x1[t], y1[t], z1[t]}, {x2[t], y2[t], z2[t]}} /. sol], {t, 
  0, 10}]
```

[image: Parametric plot of chaotic motion of a double spherical pendulum.]

We can see the path of the first pendulum in blue, and the second in yellow.

---

**Animation:**

Because I couldn't stop myself, I decided to make an animation of what this might look like.

```
pendulum1[t_] := Evaluate[{x1[t], y1[t], z1[t]} /. sol]
pendulum2[t_] := Evaluate[{x2[t], y2[t], z2[t]} /. sol]
frames = Table[
   Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[
     {x1[t], y1[t], z1[t]} /. sol,
     {t, Max[0, time - 5], time},
     ColorFunction -> (Directive[Red, Opacity[#4]] &)
     ],
    ParametricPlot3D[
     {x2[t], y2[t], z2[t]} /. sol,
     {t, Max[0, time - 5], time},
     ColorFunction -> (Directive[Blue, Opacity[#4]] &)
     ],
    Graphics3D[{
      Black,
      Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 0.02],
      Line[{{0, 0, 0}, pendulum1[time]}],
      Line[{pendulum1[time], pendulum2[time]}],
      Red,
      Ball[pendulum1[time], 0.1],
      Blue,
      Ball[pendulum2[time], 0.1]
      }
     ],
    Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
    Boxed -> False,
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}},
    ImageSize -> 500,
    ViewAngle -> 17 Degree
    ],
   {time, 0.01, 10, 0.05}
   ];
Export["~/Desktop/sphericalPendulum.gif", frames, 
 "DisplayDurations" -> 0.05]
```

(Actually, I had to decrease the resolution and number of frames in order to make the GIF small enough for upload.) Due to the `"DisplayDurations"` option, this should play at approximately real speed, i.e. 1 "unit" of time passes in the simulation for ever real second that passes.

[image: Animation of chaotic motion of double spherical pendulum.]

---

**EDIT:**

It seems like I misunderstood the question in your post, sorry about that. Your method should work. I haven't tried it with the equations you found because I'm way too lazy to type out the one million characters necessary, but we can adapt some code I've already used. I switched the symbol names from $\phi$ and $\theta$ to `phi` and `theta` since you probably can't input symbols in Java. I'm also replacing all of the derivatives with your d/dd notation and removing any `[t]`s.

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"]
x1[t_] := l1 Sin[theta1[t]] Cos[phi1[t]]
y1[t_] := l1 Sin[theta1[t]] Sin[phi1[t]]
z1[t_] := -l1 Cos[theta1[t]]
x2[t_] := x1[t] + l2 Sin[theta2[t]] Cos[phi2[t]]
y2[t_] := y1[t] + l2 Sin[theta2[t]] Sin[phi2[t]]
z2[t_] := z1[t] - l2 Cos[theta2[t]]
L = m1 (x1'[t]^2 + y1'[t]^2 + z1'[t]^2)/2 + 
    m2 (x2'[t]^2 + y2'[t]^2 + z2'[t]^2)/2 - m1 g z1[t] - m2 g z2[t] //
    FullSimplify;
ee = EulerEquations[L, {phi1[t], theta1[t], phi2[t], theta2[t]}, t] //
   FullSimplify;
eqns = ee /. {
   Derivative[1][theta1][t] -> theta1d,
   Derivative[1][theta2][t] -> theta2d,
   Derivative[1][phi1][t] -> phi1d,
   Derivative[1][phi2][t] -> phi2d,
   Derivative[2][theta1][t] -> theta1dd,
   Derivative[2][theta2][t] -> theta2dd,
   Derivative[2][phi1][t] -> phi1dd,
   Derivative[2][phi2][t] -> phi2dd,
   a_[t] :> a
   };
Solve[eqns, {theta1dd, theta2dd, phi1dd, phi2dd}]
```

I'm afraid the output is long and ugly. I'm not sure if there's a simpler form. You could try another `FullSimplify`, but it would probably require you to manually rearrange things for it to be simpler. If it's possible, I would still recommend sticking to the Lagrangian method I show in my above examples, but if you can just copy and paste the functions, it might not be too much work to use the acceleration method. Since they're all elemental functions I think it will still run fairly quickly despite being so long.

Comment: bruh, I can't believe u can do this type of stuff in mathematica, wtf. Since I'm programming in java, and I don't have access to the Euler-Lagrange equation solver, do you think there is anyway to slightly modify your code so that it could spit out an equation that directly represents the acceleration. [this link](https://myphysicslab.com/pendulum/double-pendulum-en.html) has the equivalent equation for a _2D_ double pendulum. (it's second from the bottom). Do you know how I could find this otherwise?

Comment: @Samuel, did you try inspecting the result of `EulerEquations[L, {ϕ1[t], θ1[t], ϕ2[t], θ2[t]}, t]`? MassDefect, this is a lovely tutorial, and as I told Samuel in another thread, this is how he should be attacking this: start simple, and slowly work yourself up to a more complicated problem.

Comment: I used evaluate to find the value of ee, and it gives me more equations that are equal to 0, are these the correct equations?

Comment: @Samuel, they are supposed to be, considering they're what MassDefect subsequently plugs into `NDSolve[]` to generate the animations.

Comment: @SamuelCobb If you have access to Mathematica or the Wolfram Engine, the easiest way is to get it to calculate the equations for you. You can also find them with $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial q'}\right) - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q} = 0$ where q is each of the 4 coordinates (so you do it 4 times to get 4 equations equal to 0). `EulerEquations` just automates this process. Yeah, MMA is a powerful tool and I'm always amazed what you can do in a few dozen lines of code. I also think animations and plots are a great way to help convey physics–equations alone don't do it for me.

Comment: @SamuelCobb Also, the equations provided by `EulerEquations` should be the same as the 4 equations on the page you linked to in your question. It was easier for me to just recalculate the EL equations than it was to type out those incredibly long equations. If you're working in Java, I'm not sure what your workflow is like - it's been a while since I used Java and I'm not familiar with its symbolic computing capabilities. You may have to just type  the equations directly from your link, or copy them from Mathematica if you have access to it.

Comment: Java isn't has mathematically inclined as mathematica (ofc) it is easier to solve for the second time derivative as acceleration [like this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jkzQ092yvCUFL1zqcXzX66sGJaH3N4I4/view?usp=sharing) and then effect velocity and the angle by this value. Is this a valid option?

Comment: So could I Solve[] for the second time derivatives in accordance to the 4 equations?

Comment: You'd have to implement something like [Runge-Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) yourself if you want to attempt replicating this in Java, @Samuel.

Comment: yeah, after looking at a few more simulations, the Runge-Kutta method actually looks less demanding.

Comment: @SamuelCobb I see, I think I misunderstood your question. You mentioned you wanted to use Lagrangian mechanics and I thought you meant you wanted to solve the pendulum using Lagrange mechanics, but you actually want the angular accelerations $\ddot{\phi_1}$, $\ddot{\phi_2}$, $\ddot{\theta_1}$, and $\ddot{\theta_2}$. You did say that, but I misunderstood. It can certainly be done, but there's a reason we usually use Lagrangian mechanics for this sort of thing. I checked the way you did it in your question (`Solve[eqns, vars]`), and it works fine. The only issue is that the output is quite long.

Comment: did you use the equations from the paper or the ones outputted by your code? sorry about the miscommunication, I was rushing this post

Comment: @SamuelCobb Well, I used the ones I generated because I couldn't be bothered to type out all the characters. The equations my code outputs aren't well suited to `Solve` due to the primes and `[t]`s, so I removed them first. I've added the exact steps I took to the post.

Comment: oh epic, I didn't see the edit. I tried running it on the equations on the paper and it went a bit funny but it might have been input error (i inputted it by hand bc the pdf is funky). Do you think I can use Simplify[] in the outputs to see if they can be simplified?

Comment: @SamuelCobb You can try. Due to their length, I would be prepared to let it run for a while. You might want to see the documentation for `Simplify` and `FullSimplify`. There are options to limit how long it's allowed to spend trying transformations before it returns the best so far.

Comment: @MassDefect Hey man, i haven't really done much with my project (bc i'm doing my igcse's rn), but what i did do was implement the equations that you so kindly provided w/ the Runge-Kutta method. And... it breaks. I have no idea why but i believe that one of the values gets exponentially large, too much so for the computer to handle and then it crashes. any idea why. i can send code

Comment: Hey @SamuelCobb , Ummm, I'm not sure. I'd really love to help. I think it's awesome that you're trying this sort of stuff. I haven't programmed in Java in probably 6 or 7 years though. Mostly I've done C, C++, Python, Matlab, and Wolfram since then. It would probably take me too long to understand what you're doing in Java. If you can give specific code, you might be better off posting on StackOverflow with a Java tag. Otherwise, I'll try to take a look, but I really can't promise anything. Sorry about that.

Comment: @MassDefect Hi again, I'm sorry it's been so long. I've just finished all my GCSE's and now I am free! If you want I could pretty easily write the file in python if you want. I can also send the java (I'm using a distro called Processing which is super easy) just so you can look at it quick. Here is another post i made asking whether it could be a issue w/ processing: https://discourse.processing.org/t/help-with-double-spherical-pendulum-animation/21229

Comment: @SamuelCobb I never explicitly used Runge-Kutta in Mathematica. All the code I used is in the post above. Since I don't explicitly choose a method, Mathematica has some algorithms to determine what it thinks will be the best method. Have you seen [Runge-Kutta implemented on Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220165/runge-kutta-implemented-on-mathematica)? It looks like the answers there implement the method manually. As always, I would recommend starting with something very simple, like the 2D pendulum and then slowly adding complexity.

Comment: the thing is i've done the 2d pendulum. and I completely understand it. It's much simpler than in 3 dimensions.

Comment: @MassDefect what i've been doing is plugging those the equations that we found for the second time derivative directly into my code. With the equation I then used this equation: θ = wt + 1/2at^2.  To find the next values. I am assuming this is the incorrect use of the Runge-Kutta...

Comment: @SamuelCobb Well, if something isn’t quite working right for you in Mathematica, I would recommend asking a new question with what code you have, what you expect the result to be, and where you think it might be going wrong. There’s not much help I can provide through comments alone, and hopefully others will see it too since I don’t have much time at the moment.

Comment: @MassDefect sorry for the bother then man. Thank again for all your work

Comment: @SamuelCobb It’s no bother. If I have time, I’ll definitely work on the new question you post. But there are lots of people on this site who know even more about RK. If you create a new question, you’ll likely get good answers from them as well.

Comment: @SamuelCobb I'm not sure if you'll see this, but I had a little bit of free time and implemented the double 3d pendulum in Python. You can email me if you like and I'd be happy to explain the process and share the code with you. I think it would be relatively easy for you to translate it into Java. There's a link in my Mathematica.SE profile that you can follow to get my University email.

Comment: Oh dang man. I'll email you right away

Comment: I admire your willingness to help and your excellent pedagogical and very structured answer. I understand, it was a pleasure for you to work on this project. But I want to warn you that people are making money on your kindness. Your answer is being circulated  on the sites selling homework solutions. Therefore, I call to provide answers only on the questions with at least a *minimum preliminary work*.

Comment: @yarchik That's a fair point, and I'll keep that in mind. I get a little carried away sometimes when it comes to modelling physics.