# Help with Runge-Kutta Order 4th with a system of 3 equations

Tags: differential-equations

I have been trying to solve a system of equations with Runge-Kutta Order 4th but when I tried to run it the answer I got is a big equation with the word List in it instead of an Array. I put n=2 because otherwise it will take the program a lot to load on my laptop.

Edit: Thanks to Nasser I don't have a problem with List but now I get as solutions some extremly big numbers. Is there a calculator online for system of equations like this or can someone tell me if its a problem with the code?

[image: This is the problem]

I replaced rho sigma and beta with v, j and c

```
Clear[f, g, u, k1, k2, k3, k4, v, i, j, c, l1, l2, l3, l4, p1, p2, \
p3, p4]
v = 28
j = 10
c = 3/8

n = 2
x = ConstantArray[0, n + 1]
y = ConstantArray[0, n + 1]
z = ConstantArray[0, n + 1]
t = ConstantArray[0, n + 1]
x[[1]] = 2
y[[1]] = 1
z[[1]] = 3
ti = 0
tf = 1
dt = (a + b)/n
t[[1]] = ti

x
y
z


f[x_, y_] := v*(y - x)
g[x_, y_, z_] := x*(j - z) - y
u[x_, y_, z_] := x*y - c*z
For[
 i = 1, i <= n, i++,
 k1 = f[x[[i]], y[[i]]];
 l1 = g[x[[i]], y[[i]], z[[i]]];
 p1 = u[x[[i]], y[[i]], z[[i]]];
 k2 = f[x[[i]] + dt/2*k1, y[[i]] + dt/2*l1];
 l2 = g[x[[i]] + dt/2*k1, y[[i]] + dt/2*l1, z[[i]] + dt/2 + p1];
 p2 = u[x[[i]] + dt/2*k1, y[[i]] + dt/2*l1, z[[i]] + dt/2 + p1];
 k3 = f[x[[i]] + dt/2*k2, y[[i]] + dt/2*l2];
 l3 = g[x[[i]] + dt/2*k2, y[[i]] + dt/2*l2, z[[i]] + dt/2 + p2];
 p3 = u[x[[i]] + dt/2*k2, y[[i]] + dt/2*l2, z[[i]] + dt/2 + p2];
 k4 = f[x[[i]] + dt*k3, y[[i]] + dt*l3];
 l4 = g[x[[i]] + dt*k3, y[[i]] + dt*l3, z[[i]] + dt*p3];
 p4 = u[x[[i]] + dt*k3, y[[i]] + dt*l3, z[[i]] + dt*p3];
 x[[i + 1]] = x[[i]] + (dt/6)*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4);
 y[[i + 1]] = y[[i]] + (dt/6)*(l1 + 2*l2 + 2*l3 + l4);
 z[[i + 1]] = z[[i]] + (dt/6)*(p1 + 2*p2 + 2*p3 + p4);
 t[[i + 1]] = t[[i]] + dt
 ]

x
y
z
```

[image]
Here is an image with the output that I get

Comment: You can not do `For[ i = 0,` then do `x[[i]]` because `x[[0]]` is the head, which is `List`. That is why you are getting `List` everywhere in your output .

Comment: If you just want to solve this ODE system, forget about RK4 and use `NDSolve` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several RK4 implementation on this forum including [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220165/runge-kutta-implemented-on-mathematica?rq=1). Let take code from Szabolcs answer and compute your system as a test

```
ClearAll[RK4step]
RK4step[f_, h_][{t_, y_}] := Module[{k1, k2, k3, k4}, k1 = f[t, y];
  k2 = f[t + h/2, y + h k1/2];
  k3 = f[t + h/2, y + h k2/2];
  k4 = f[t + h, y + h k3];
  {t + h, y + h/6*(k1 + 2 k2 + 2 k3 + k4)}]
v = 28;
j = 10;
c = 3/8;
f[t_, {x_, y1_, z_}] := {v*(y1 - x), x*(j - z) - y1, x*y1 - c*z}


res = NestList[RK4step[f, 1/100], {0, {2., 1., 3.}}, 100];
```

Visualization

```
 p = ListLinePlot[
  Table[Transpose[{res[[All, 1]], res[[All, 2, i]]}], {i, 3}] // 
   Evaluate, PlotLegends -> {"x", "y", "z"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Now we can compute `x,y,z` with your code

```
Clear[x, y, z, f]

n = 100;
x = ConstantArray[0, n + 1];
y = ConstantArray[0, n + 1];
z = ConstantArray[0, n + 1];
t = ConstantArray[0, n + 1];
x[[1]] = 2.;
y[[1]] = 1.;
z[[1]] = 3.;
ti = 0;
tf = 1;
dt = 1/n;
t[[1]] = ti;
f[x_, y_] := v*(y - x)
g[x_, y_, z_] := x*(j - z) - y
u[x_, y_, z_] := x*y - c*z
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, k1 = f[x[[i]], y[[i]]];
 l1 = g[x[[i]], y[[i]], z[[i]]];
 p1 = u[x[[i]], y[[i]], z[[i]]];
 k2 = f[x[[i]] + dt/2*k1, y[[i]] + dt/2*l1];
 l2 = g[x[[i]] + dt/2*k1, y[[i]] + dt/2*l1, z[[i]] + dt/2 p1];
 p2 = u[x[[i]] + dt/2*k1, y[[i]] + dt/2*l1, z[[i]] + dt/2 p1];
 k3 = f[x[[i]] + dt/2*k2, y[[i]] + dt/2*l2];
 l3 = g[x[[i]] + dt/2*k2, y[[i]] + dt/2*l2, z[[i]] + dt/2 p2];
 p3 = u[x[[i]] + dt/2*k2, y[[i]] + dt/2*l2, z[[i]] + dt/2 p2];
 k4 = f[x[[i]] + dt*k3, y[[i]] + dt*l3];
 l4 = g[x[[i]] + dt*k3, y[[i]] + dt*l3, z[[i]] + dt*p3];
 p4 = u[x[[i]] + dt*k3, y[[i]] + dt*l3, z[[i]] + dt*p3];
 x[[i + 1]] = x[[i]] + (dt/6)*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4);
 y[[i + 1]] = y[[i]] + (dt/6)*(l1 + 2*l2 + 2*l3 + l4);
 z[[i + 1]] = z[[i]] + (dt/6)*(p1 + 2*p2 + 2*p3 + p4);
 t[[i + 1]] = t[[i]] + dt]
```

Please, pay attention that several typos removed from your code. Visualization and comparison with Szabolcs code

```
Show[p, ListPlot[{Transpose[{t[[All]], x[[All]]}], 
   Transpose[{t[[All]], y[[All]]}], Transpose[{t[[All]], z[[All]]}]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}]]
```

[image: Figure 2]